В чем разница между запросом Postman`a и CURL`fа?
Хочу спарсить список аэропортов с сайта https://www.koreanair.com/, он предоставляет список в виде json по этой ссылке
https://www.koreanair.com/api/et/route/c/a/getReservationAirport?airportCode=&directionType=D&flowType=RE&langCode=ru&nationCode=nl&tripType=RO
При запросе с postman`а все получается: 
Но при эквивалентном запросе через CURL:
$url = "https://www.koreanair.com/api/et/route/c/a/getReservationAirport?airportCode=&directionType=D&flowType=RE&langCode=ru&nationCode=nl&tripType=RO";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$header = [
    "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,br",
    "Connection:keep-alive",
    "Accept:*/*",
    "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch) || substr($info['http_code'], 0, 1) !== '2') {
    var_export(curl_error($ch));
    var_export($data);
    var_export($info);
}

Выдает следующее:
'Recv failure: Connection was reset'falsearray ( 'url' => 'https://www.koreanair.com/api/et/route/c/a/getReservationAirport?airportCode=&directionType=D&flowType=RE&langCode=ru&nationCode=nl&tripType=RO', 'content_type' => NULL, 'http_code' => 0, 'header_size' => 0, 'request_size' => 173, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_result' => 20, 'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' => 0.426461, 'namelookup_time' => 0.094612, 'connect_time' => 0.176895, 'pretransfer_time' => 0.262785, 'size_upload' => 0.0, 'size_download' => 0.0, 'speed_download' => 0.0, 'speed_upload' => 0.0, 'download_content_length' => -1.0, 'upload_content_length' => 0.0, 'starttransfer_time' => 0.0, 'redirect_time' => 0.0, 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '2.18.29.201', 'certinfo' => array ( ), 'primary_port' => 443, 'local_ip' => '192.168.0.12', 'local_port' => 26996, 'http_version' => 0, 'protocol' => 2, 'ssl_verifyresult' => 0, 'scheme' => 'HTTPS', 'appconnect_time_us' => 262738, 'connect_time_us' => 176895, 'namelookup_time_us' => 94612, 'pretransfer_time_us' => 262785, 'redirect_time_us' => 0, 'starttransfer_time_us' => 0, 'total_time_us' => 426461, 'effective_method' => 'GET', 'capath' => '', 'cainfo' => '', )

